# Setting headerBackground in code for the material DatePicker

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to change the style of the header in the new `DatePicker`. I can set this in XML using the follow:

```
android:headerBackground="@color/myColor" />
```

However I can't find a way to do this in code. The usual setters don't seem to be apparent (i.e `datePicker.setHeaderBackground`).

Any ideas?